# Refresh plot during heavy calculations

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I have some heavy calculations with generates huge list of `{x, y}` points. I want to dynamically update plot during calculations. Or update it after calculations complete. I can't use simple `Dynamic @ Plot`, because it makes calculation time 5-10x times longer. So I made some example, how I tried to solve this problem. But it didn't work.

```
Manipulate[None, 
  Grid[
    {{Dynamic[
        ListPlot[
          Refresh[pts, UpdateInterval -> 5], 
          PlotRange -> All], 
        UpdateInterval -> 2], 
      SpanFromLeft, 
      SpanFromLeft}, 
     {Slider[Dynamic[a], {10, 20, 1}], 
      Dynamic@ProgressIndicator[i, {1, a}], 
      Button["Run", func[], Method -> "Queued"]}}], 
  TrackedSymbols :> {}, 
  ContinuousAction -> False, 
  SynchronousUpdating -> False, LocalizeVariables -> True, 
  Initialization :> (
    pts = {{0, 0}}; a = 10; i = 1; 
    func[] := 
     Module[{}, 
       For[i = 1;, i < a, i++, Pause[.5]; AppendTo[pts, {i, i}]]])]
```

So how can I refresh plot only every n seconds? Or refresh after all calculations complete?

Comment: Can't you just run the plot at the end of the notebook?

Comment: `ListPlot[]` has to do a lot of fancy stuff. If you just need a graphical monitor, go raw: `Graphics[Point[pts], Axes -> True]`.

Answer (score 5):

Your `Manipulate` expression works for me when I change your button specification to

```
Button["Run", pts = {{0, 0}}; func[], Method -> "Queued"]
```

However, I think it would better to replace your unnecessarily complicated `Manipulate` expression with a simple `DynamicModule` expression.

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{0, 0}}, a = 10, i = 1, func},
  func[] := Do[Pause[.5]; AppendTo[pts, {i, i}], {i, a}];
  Dynamic @ Grid[
    {{ListPlot[pts, PlotRange -> All], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
     {Slider[Dynamic[a], {10, 20, 1}], 
      ProgressIndicator[i, {1, a}],
      Button["Run", pts = {{0, 0}}; func[], Method -> "Queued"]}}]]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: U don't explain how can i fix my problem. U didn't use update interval in your example. Finger Down.

Answer (score 4):

Option 1: Use the `UpdateInterval` option to `Dynamics`, i.e.,

```
Dynamic[Plot[...],UpdateInterval->n,TrackedSymbols->{}]
```

where `n` is measure in seconds. Here, `UpdateInterval` is how often `Dynamic` "manually" updates the expression.  By default it will also update it any time one of the symbols is changed, so you also need to set `TrackedSymbols->{}`.

Option 2: Use a dummy dataset in the `Dynamics` function, and only update that variable at the desired pace.  For example,

```
Print[Dynamic[Plot[dummyData,...]]]; ...calculation code...; dummyData=newData;
```

Comment: I updated this answer to reflect the issue `Wjx` pointed out.

Comment: When i used Option 1: Dynamic[ListPlot[pts, PlotRange -> All], UpdateInterval ->  2, 
 TrackedSymbols -> {}] Plot is always empty. It doen't refresh. Option 2 can work, but not good because of huge variables. Memory is limited. But thx.

Comment: I just doubled checked with the code from your comment, and it works for me.  Did you try it without `Dynamic`?  Did you try it with both `UpdateInterval` and `TrackedSymbols` removed.  Are you sure `pts` is good data, so that `ListPlot[pts]` works?

Answer (score 2):

Though similar to @Jess's answer, I think this will work as you want.

```
Dynamic[PLOT,UpdateInterval->10,TrackedSymbols->{}]
```

Because UpdateInterval only set the **Max** Update interval!! So as your data is updating at a almost crazy speed, the plot will sense the change of your data and update crazily as well. You have to manually tell Dynamic: don't track data, simply follow the UpdateInterval!!!

Hope this can help u.

Comment: Yea, this is tweak is necessary.  Hope you don't mind I update my answer.

Comment: @JessRiedel Don't mind at all~